# c# custom model binder for specific model and specific variable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have myself a problem with nullable ints and validation text.

Basically I want to change the validation message which is shown when a nullable int is not provided

so from

```
"The value 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is invalid"
```

to

```
"Please provide a valid number"
```

I have myself a custom model binder like so

```
public class IntModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var integerValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (integerValue == null || integerValue.AttemptedValue == "")
                return null;

            var integer = integerValue.AttemptedValue;

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName));
            try
            {
                return int.Parse(integer);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, String.Format("\"{0}\" is invalid, please provide a valid number.", bindingContext.ModelName));
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

now at the moment I have updated my global.asax.cs so all nullable ints use this model binder, however I don't want all nullable ints to use this, I just want a specific model to use it and only use my model binder on the nullable ints in that model. Is there a way I can bind this modelbinder to my model and only associate with the nullable int variables?

I have tried to use my modebinder on my model like so

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(IntModelBinder))]
public class CreateQuoteModel
{
    ....
}
```

But it doesn't check on the nullable ints, I would like to avoid third party addons

Answer (score 1):

You are returning null on nullable ints

```
if (integerValue == null || integerValue.AttemptedValue == "")
   return null;
```

so you are not adding that error to your modelsatate on nullable ints. 
Also I suggest you to use

```
int result=0;
if(!int.TryParse(integer, out result)){
   bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, String.Format("\"{0}\" is invalid, please provide a valid number.", bindingContext.ModelName));
   return null;
}
return result;
```

instead of your Exception handling flow to avoid this anti-pattern

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't solve my actual problem

Answer (score 1):

Surely so long as you have a nullable int on your model and the required attribute with a custom message this would work?

Conversely you could use a regex match which checks for length and type

Comment: This doesn't work because the model binder takes over all of the value checks, so it misses all of the strings and datetimes that would be inside of the model

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You add attributes to all of the required fields that validate them for you. If you need custom behaviour, create a custom attribute and uses the appropriate interfaces.